# Unable to drag window due to tkinter after command

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a small function to create scrolling text within a tkinter canvas. It works well except I cannot drag the containing window. I suspect this is because the time period is quite short. Any thoughts welcomed.

In the code below self.widget is the canvas and self.text is the canvas object which contains text.

```
    def scroll_text(self):

        if self.current_ticker_text == "":
            return
        self.view.root.update()  # refresh wondow to ensure we get proper widget width else it will return a '1'
        self.text = self.widget.create_text(self.widget.winfo_width() - 200, 10, anchor='nw',
                                            text=self.current_ticker_text)
        self._scrolling()


    def _scrolling(self):
        if self.text is None:
            return
        self.widget.move(self.text, -1, 0)
        self.widget.update()

        ticker_timer = self.view.root.after(15, self._scrolling)
        bbox_result = self.widget.bbox(self.text)

        if bbox_result is not None:
            if  bbox_result[2] < -5:

                self.scroll_text()
                self.view.root.after_cancel(ticker_timer)
```

I am expecting to be able to drag the window around the screen and still have the text scrolling.

Comment: There is a problem with your example. `self.text` tagorid is referenced before it's validity is checked. Also `self.scroll_text()` is only called once, after `self.text` scrolls off the canvas.

Comment: Code tweaked but had no change in behaviour.   I've edited code in original and added in the other function s I seemed to have missed that off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the line self.widget.update() and placed it after the self.view.root.after_cancel(ticker_timer) line.  All works now